# Tengo un problema con FileInputStream a la hora de leer un archivo en la memoria externa

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando un app para encriptar archivos y tengo un problema que no logro solucionar por ningún lado, mi aplicación pide los permisos necesarios para leer y escribir archivos con el siguiente código:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
&& ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

  try {

                    encriptar(clave);

                } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException k) {

                    throw new RuntimeException(k);

                }
}
```

Mi función `encriptar()` lee un archivo de la tarjeta sd para encriptarlo:

```
  public void encriptar(String clave)throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {

    //Archivo de entrada

    String direccion =  "/sdcard/Archivo.txt";

    Toast.makeText(this,"Leyendo archivo: "+direccion,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        FileInputStream Entrada = new FileInputStream(direccion);


        //Archivo de salida, encriptado
        FileOutputStream Salida = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/salida.txt");

        // ¡Cuidado al tomar la entrada del usuario! Https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452620/1188357

        //Tamaño de el arhivo  16 bytes

        SecretKey sks = new SecretKeySpec(clave.getBytes(), "AES");

        //Se crea el cipher, se encargan de encriptar los byte

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);

        //stream de salida
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(Salida, cipher);

        //escribe bytes

        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        int b = Entrada.read(d);

        while (b != -1) {

            cos.write(d, 0, b);

            b = Entrada.read(d);
        }

        //cierra streams
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        Entrada.close();
    }
```

Y me sale el siguiente error al ejecutar el código:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Archivo.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

El problema parece ser con el archivo de Entrada que no lo encuentra
ya intente cambiándole el nombre al directorio, dejándolo solo como

```
String direccion = "Archivo.txt";
```

también así:

```
String direccion =  "/"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName()+"/Archivo.txt";
```

o así:

```
 String direccion =  "/0/Archivo.txt";
```

y me sigue saliendo el mismo error, pensé que eran los permisos pero ya los pedí en el Manifest y en ejecución, no se porque no me lee el archivo
me sale este error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: user.user.pruebaencryptararchivos, PID: 7910
>                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Archivo.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>                                                                                             at user.user.pruebaencryptararchivos.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21215)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Archivo.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

¿alguien me podría ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente intento comprobar antes si la memoria externa está disponible o si tiene acceso de lectura, escritura o ambas. Una vez comprobado esto suelo comprobar si el archivo que deseo obtener existe o no, y por último una vez estén hechas estas comprobaciones suelo realizar las acciones sobre el archivo.

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo de código de cómo realizo todas estas comprobaciones para realizar operaciones en el almacenamiento externo.

```
try{
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

      boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
      boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

      // COMPROBACION DEL ALMACENAMIENTO EXTERNO
      if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
          // Podremos leer y escribir en ella
          mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
      } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
          // En este caso solo podremos leer los datos
          mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
          mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
      } else {
          // No podremos leer ni escribir en ella
          mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
      }

      //Comprobamos si existe el fichero en almacenamiento externo
      if(mExternalStorageAvailable){

          String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
          String fileName = "Archivo.txt";

          File archivo = new File(baseDir + File.Separator + fileName);
          Log.i(tag, "ruta externa: " + archivo .toString());

          if(archivo .exists()){
              FileInputStream Entrada = new FileInputStream(archivo);

              //haces el encriptado
          }
       }

} catch (Exception ex) {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /sdcard/Archivo.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

generalmente sucede al no existir el archivo que se intenta abrir o no definir correctamente el path donde se encuentra el archivo.

De hecho puedes comprobarlo mediante:

```
String direccion =  "/sdcard/Archivo.txt";

File file = new File(direccion);
 if(file.exists()){
              FileInputStream Entrada = new FileInputStream(archivo);
 }else{
   Log.e("Encriptar", "No existe el archivo especificado!");
 }
```

**Para encontrar el path de la SDCard, evita harcodear el path!**, esta es la forma de obtener la ruta y el archivo, mediante [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"Archivo.txt");
```